# React POST Request (MERN Stack)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, mern

I am having trouble posting form data to MongoDB when testing on my local development environment. The endpoint that I am trying to post to is https://localhost:5000/users/add and I have been able to successfully post data to MongoDB using a REST API client and have also verified that my frontend is hooked up to my backend. I think there is something wrong with how I have setup my form, can someone please help? I am using axios library to send the request. Thank you in advance :)

package.json (client side code, I have set the proxy to https://localhost:5000/):

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000/",
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.30",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.14.0",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.11",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "axios": "^0.21.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.6",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-datepicker": "^3.1.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-hook-form": "^6.8.2",
    "react-images-upload": "^1.2.8",
    "react-modal": "^3.11.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "^3.4.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {}
}
```

ReactJS form:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'; 
import Modal from 'react-modal'; 
import Exit from '../cancel.svg'; 
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form"; 
import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";
import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import { faEye } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import axios from "axios"; 
const eye = <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faEye} />;

Modal.setAppElement('#root')

const Register = () => {

    const [modalIsOpen, setModalIsOpen] = useState (true) 
    const { register, handleSubmit, errors } = useForm ();
    const [date, setDate] = useState(new Date("06/06/1994")); 
    const onSubmit = (data) => {data['birthdate']= date; console.log(data)}; 
    const [firstName, setfirstName] = useState(""); 
    const [lastName, setlastName] = useState(""); 
    // const [birthdate, setbirthdate] = useState(""); 
    const [gender, setGender] = useState(""); 
    const [email, setemail] = useState(""); 
    const [password, setpassword] = useState(""); 
    const [city, setcity] = useState(""); 
    const [passwordShown, setPasswordShown] = useState(false);
    const togglePasswordVisiblity = () => {
        setPasswordShown(passwordShown ? false : true);    
      };  
    
      const changeOnClick = e => {
          e.preventDefault(); 

          const users = {
              firstName, 
              lastName, 
              date, 
              gender, 
              email, 
              password, 
              city
          };

          axios
            .post("/users/add", users)
            .then(res => console.log(res.data))
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err); 
            }); 
      }; 

    return(
        <Modal isOpen={modalIsOpen} onRequestClose={() => setModalIsOpen(false)} className='createBorder'>
        <form onSubmit={changeOnClick} encType="multipart/form-data">
            <div className='border-bottom'>
                    <img onClick= {() => setModalIsOpen(false)} src={Exit} className='exitButton-two' alt='X' />
                    <span className='create-an-account'>Create an account</span> 
            </div>
            <div className='material' onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
                <p className='fieldsOne'>First name:</p>
                <input onChange={e => setfirstName(e.target.value)} name='firstName' ref={register({required: true})} className='inputs' autoComplete='off'></input>
                <p className='minifields'>This information will display on your profile</p>
                {errors.firstName && <span className='registerRequired'>This field is required</span>}
                <p className='fields'>Last name:</p>
                <input onChange={e => setlastName(e.target.value)} name='lastName' ref={register({required: true})} className='inputs' autoComplete='off'></input>
                <p className='minifields'>This information will display on your profile</p>
                {errors.lastName && <span className='registerRequired'>This field is required</span>}
                <p className='fields'>Birthdate:</p>
                    <DatePicker
                        ref={register({required: true})}
                        dateFormat="MM/dd/yyyy"
                        selected={date}
                        name='birthdate'
                        onChange={date => setDate(date)}
                        // onChange={e => setbirthdate(e.target.value)}
                        />           
                <p className='minifields'>We'll use this information when considering what films you are qualified to test</p>
                {errors.birthday && <span className='registerRequired'>This field is required</span>}
                <p className='fields'>Gender</p>
                <select name='Gender' ref={register({required: false})} className='inputs' onChange={e => setGender(e.target.value)}>
                    <option value="">Select...</option>
                    <option value="male">Male</option>
                    <option value="female">Female</option>
                    <option value="other">Other</option>
                </select>
                <p className='minifields'>This information will display on your profile</p>
                <p className='fields'>Email:</p>
                <input onChange={e => setemail(e.target.value)} name='email' ref={register({required: true})} className='inputs' autoComplete='off'></input>
                <p className='minifields'>We'll email you when films are for screening that fits your profile</p>
                {errors.email && <span className='registerRequired'>This field is required</span>}
                <div>
                    <p className='fields'>Password:</p>
                    <input onChange={e => setpassword(e.target.value)} type={passwordShown ? "text" : "password"} name='password' ref={register({required: true})} className='inputs' autoComplete='off'></input>
                    <i className='eye' onClick={togglePasswordVisiblity}>{eye}</i>
                </div>
                <p className='minifields'>You'll need one of these guys to sign in later.</p>
                {errors.password && <span className='registerRequired'>This field is required</span>}
                <p className='fields'>City:</p>
                <input onChange={e => setcity(e.target.value)} name='city' ref={register({required: true})} className='inputs' autoComplete='off'></input>
                <p className='minifields'>This information will display on your profile</p>
                {errors.city && <span className='registerRequired'>This field is required</span>}
            </div>
            <div className='alignalign'>
                {/* <button type='submit'>submit</button> */}
                <a href='/GetStarted/completeProfile' onClick={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} type='submit' className='signupButton'>Sign Up</a>
            </div>
        </form>
        </Modal>
    )
}

export default Register;
```

Express BE:

```
const express = require ("express"); 
const router = express.Router(); 
const Users = require("../models/users"); 


router.get('/', (req,res) => {
    Users.find()
        .then(user => res.json(user))
        .catch(err => res.status(400).json(`Err: ${err}`)); 
}); 

//REQUEST TO ADD NEW USER
router.post('/add', (req, res) => {
    const newUser = new Users({
        firstName: req.body.firstName, 
        lastName: req.body.lastName, 
        birthdate: req.body.birthdate, 
        gender: req.body.gender, 
        email: req.body.email, 
        password: req.body.password, 
        city: req.body.password, 
        shareEmail: req.body.shareEmail, 
        filmmakerQuestion: req.body.filmmakerQuestion, 
        genres: req.body.genres, 
        favoriteFilms: req.body.favoriteFilms, 
        imbd: req.body.imbd, 
        portfolio: req.body.portfolio, 
        aboutYou: req.body.aboutYou, 
    })

    newUser.save()
    .then(() => res.json("The new User posted successfully!"))
    .catch(err => res.status(400).json(`Error: ${err}`)); 
});
```

Comment: Is "/users/add" the correct route for the POST request for your API?

Comment: Hi @DrewReese when I try https://localhost:5000/users/add while I see the data gets logged to the console, the data is not added to the database. Additionally I do see a number of warnings in my console "Field missing name attribute" which logs every time I input a new character (and I have not been able to resolve this warning).

Comment: @DrewReese a final note is that the form does not refresh on submission.

Comment: Did you try to console.log(req.body)  ?

Comment: The form doesn't reset because you `preventDefault` on the `onSubmit` event object. So are you saying the POST request is successful but your DB just isn't updating? How/where are you verifying/validating the DB update?

Comment: @DrewReese if I comment out the prevent default and input all required fields on my form, the form still does not refresh onSubmit event. It seems like the POST request doesn't even process as I am not seeing any sort of error or success in the console. Could it be an issue with how my button is setup on my form?

Comment: @VipinGautam I am not able to compile the code when I update to console.log(req.body)

Comment: @DrewReese when I do update my button to use the one that is commented out I receive the following error in the console - POST https://localhost:5000/users/add net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Comment: Try using tunnel or ngrok and see if it's work